Unable to complete install: 'unsupported configuration: System lacks NETNS support'
I'm trying to bring up a NAT virtual network, but it errors saying "Unable to complete install: 'unsupported configuration: System lacks NETNS support'"


that is extremely unlikely. Network namespaces are a standard linux kernel feature, your system HAS netns unless you specifically disabled it when you manually built a kernel. Perhaps you're trying to add a new virtual network in a mode that requires you to be root? Or are you running libvirtd as a user with no subuid/subgid mappings?

I'm using the stock Arch kernel, and I'm running libvirtd as root.

Please edit your post to include these details in the question body.

I have the same problem on both my Manjaro machines, I tried switching to older LTS kernels but still the same issue, but there is no problem whatsoever with my VMs so I don't really think it's a libvirtd issue.

What is the output of cat /location/of/.config | grep NETNS where location of .config is the directory where you built the kernel according to either of the 2 methods in the handbook

I use a stock Manjaro kernel, running libvirtd as root too.
`# zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_NET_NS
CONFIG_NET_NS=y
CONFIG_NET_NSH=m
CONFIG_NET_NS_REFCNT_TRACKER is not set`

I found this today https://lists.libvirt.org/archives/list/devel@lists.libvirt.org/thread/UO2M726GGCQRIJ7UIMPU3BVQ5JMVQPDZ/
I don't know if this is related to my issue.
